# How to disable cache nginx

Tags: nginx

The remote type is cached and displays an illegal ip for the new user. It helps wait 3-10 seconds or restart nginx. How to completely turn off caching?

OS: Centos 7
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    server {
        listen              80;
        server_name         test.mydomain.org;
        root                /etc/nginx/html;
        index   index.html;

        location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
            default_type text/plain;
            return 200 "$remote_addr";
        }
        # Error page
        error_page  404    /404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact error message and which line is causing it?

Comment: There is no error, just returns the old ip, which is in the cache.

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: use proxy and see on myip.com / myip.ru (see proxy ip), and my site (old ip).  If restart nginx, im see proxy ip

Comment: Use a new incognito browser to check your page or use curl. Don't use browser as it will cache the page

Comment: im use chrome with dev console checked "Disable cache"

Comment: Still try with curl and see what you get?

Comment: This all does not change the main thing that when you change the IP and do not use the incognito mode on myip.com / myip.ru sites, it changes immediately, and that's exactly what I need.

Comment: I am just asking you to check so we know if it is server side cache for both curl and browser or just for browser

Comment: yes, ip changed if use curl

Comment: That means the issue is with headers related to caching

Comment: im use all header for cache off, but didnt work:
http://6pic.ru/2017-08-24_145832.jpg

Comment: nginx.conf https://pastebin.com/rgvLK2dc

Comment: Try adding `expires 0;` also to your location

Comment: Still does not work, `expires 0;` and `expires -1;`

Answer (score 9):

The caching you are seeing is from the browser cache.
Clear the browser cache and try the page after resetting the location  conf to include:

```
    # kill cache
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'private no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
```

This makes absolutely sure the browser or any intermediate proxy will not cache the output sent.

Comment: nginx.conf https://pastebin.com/yWgT9twq + browser http request http://6pic.ru/2017-08-24_174216.jpg

Comment: I have implemented your config on my server and it works fine every single time. No issues even without `disable cache` in network tab

Comment: How you test? Browser with activated proxy/tor (not incognito), open site, change ip (not close browser), refresh page

Answer (score 0):

use this configuration in nginx conf file

```
location /path-to-files/ {
directio 0;
}
```

which will bypass OS level cache.